# CodeDeploy Bitbucket - How to Fail Bitbucket on CodeDeploy Failure

Tags: aws-code-deploy, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a successful bitbucket pipeline calling out to aws CodeDeploy, but I'm wondering if I can add a step that will check and wait for CodeDeploy success, otherwise fail the pipeline. Would this just be possible with a script that loops through a CodeDeploy call that continues to monitor the status of the CodeDeploy push? Any idea what CodeDeploy call that would be?

*bitbucket-pipline.yml*

```
image: pitech/gradle-awscli

pipelines:
  branches:
develop:
  - step:
      caches:
        - gradle
      script:
        - gradle build bootRepackage
        - mkdir tmp; cp appspec.yml tmp; cp build/libs/thejar*.jar tmp/the.jar; cp -r scripts/ ./tmp/
        - pip install awscli --upgrade --user
        - aws deploy push --s3-location s3://thebucket/the-deploy.zip --application-name my-staging-app --ignore-hidden-files --source tmp
        - aws deploy create-deployment --application-name server-staging --s3-location bucket=staging-codedeploy,key=the-deploy.zip,bundleType=zip --deployment-group-name the-staging --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce --file-exists-behavior=OVERWRITE
```

*appspec.yml*

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: thejar.jar
    destination: /home/ec2-user/the-server/

permissions:
  - object: /
    pattern: "**"
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user

hooks:
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/server_stop.sh
      timeout: 60
      runas: ec2-user
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/server_start.sh
      timeout: 60
      runas: ec2-user
  ValidateService:
    - location: scripts/server_validate.sh
      timeout: 120
      runas: ec2-user
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem like Bitbucket is waiting for the ValidateService to complete, so I'd need a way in Bitbucket to confirm before marking the build a success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aws deploy create-deployment` is an asynchronous call, and BitBucket has no idea that it needs to know about the success of your deployment. Adding a script to your CodeDeploy application will have no effect on BitBucket knowing about your deployment.

You have one (maybe two) options to fix this issue.

#### #1 Include a script that waits for your deployment to finish

You need to add a script to your BitBucket pipeline to check the status of your deployment to finish. You can either use SNS notifications, or poll the CodeDeploy service directly.

The pseudocode would look something like this:

```
loop
    check_if_deployment_complete
    if false, wait and retry
    if true && deployment successful, return 0 (success)
    if true && deployment failed, return non-zero (failure)
```

You can use the AWS CLI or your favorite scripting language. Add it at the end of your `bitbucket-pipline.yml` script. Make sure you use a wait between calls to CodeDeploy to check the status.

#### #2 (the maybe) Use BitBucket AWS CodeDeploy integration directly

BitBucket integrates with AWS CodeDeploy directly, so you might be able to use their integration rather than your script to integration properly. I don't know if this is supported or not.

Answer (score 2):

AWS CLI already has a `deployment-successful` method which checks the status of a deployment every 15 seconds. You just need to pipe the output of `create-deployment` to `deployment-successful`.

In your specific case, it should look like this:

```
image: pitech/gradle-awscli

pipelines:
  branches:
develop:
  - step:
      caches:
        - gradle
      script:
        - gradle build bootRepackage
        - mkdir tmp; cp appspec.yml tmp; cp build/libs/thejar*.jar tmp/the.jar; cp -r scripts/ ./tmp/
        - pip install awscli --upgrade --user
        - aws deploy push --s3-location s3://thebucket/the-deploy.zip --application-name my-staging-app --ignore-hidden-files --source tmp
        - aws deploy create-deployment --application-name server-staging --s3-location bucket=staging-codedeploy,key=the-deploy.zip,bundleType=zip --deployment-group-name the-staging --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce --file-exists-behavior=OVERWRITE > deployment.json
        - aws deploy wait deployment-successful --cli-input-json file://deployment.json
```